# Exposed filters and views dependent filters

Tags: php, drupal-7, view

I am using drupal commerce. I created my products and made my exposed filters ordered by taxonomies that I had recently  made. Now I want to link those filters in a specific hierarchy, each product had a specific types. For example :
printer has three types,scanner has four types .
If user selects printer in the product commerce type, the exposed filter for type shows the three types related to printer. I found a module called views dependent filter that may do this. Any suggestions to help me? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to look into https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi , If you are going multi level deep it is very useful